# Is there a formula to fix this issue?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I download any report from my local bank, the first thing I want to do is sort it by the DATE field. However, their DATE field is formatted as GENERAL (no specific number format (you'd think a bank would know better)! Therefore, 1/27/2023 sorts lower than 1/3/2023 - or - 12/1/2023 sorts lower than 2/1/2023. Is there a formula I can use to pad ZEROS or to change the format/syntax from 9/9/9999 to 99/99/9999? I imagine the first thing I need to do is to change it to numeric(?) but I'm not successful in doing that. (and, yes, I hate my bank).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1. See https://superuser.com/questions/335132/how-do-i-parse-a-nonstandard-date-format-in-excel  2. Have you tried DATEVALUE()? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/convert-dates-stored-as-text-to-dates-8df7663e-98e6-4295-96e4-32a67ec0a680

Comment: In addition to the solutions already proposed, you can try using a method without formulas at all: select the entire column with incorrect dates, select [**Data > Text to Columns**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) and immediately, on the first screen of the Wizard, click OK

Comment: Try multiplying the values by 1 and then format as a date.